# How to show a separate fragment in a pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, fragmentpageradapter

Based on the default "Fixed Tabs + Swipe" activity in the ADT, I have a `FragmentActivity` with a `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

The `FragementPagerAdapter` is very simple (just returns a certain fragment based on the called position) and at the moment the `FragmentActivity` itself is also pretty default from the 'example' code Eclipse provides. The 'interesting' parts are attached at the end, but this is how it looks (obviously simplified for question-purposes)

[image]

Now in one of the various fragments, I have a button that should show some information and a picture / pictures: something that does not really belong in the tabbed-view.

**What is the best method for this?**

I thought about either just starting a new activity, but this is discouraged in favor of building with fragments, so I discarded that option. Then I could just make a 'random' fragment to show, but I'm not sure how to implement that in regard to the pager -> this might actually be the best way.

What I could come up with was to show a `DialogFragment`. I've actually implemented this like so:

First create a DialogFragment with this `onCreateView`:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.entry, container, false);
    //set image
    return v;
}
```

and show it like so:

```
fragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");
```

the xml is a simple linearLayout that was suggested on stackoverflow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:minWidth="1000dp"  
    android:minHeight="1000dp"> 

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_desc" 
         />

 </LinearLayout>
```

The problem here is that while this is shown allright, it seems that there is something (the title bar for the pager? not sure) is added above the picture:

[image]

It's hard to see, but I believe it is directly in line with the bottom of the pager-fragment-titles, so I seem to have 'inherited' some features?

**Current base-code**

From the onCreate in the `FragmentActivity`

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
...

mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
    getSupportFragmentManager());
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

The `SectionsPagerAdapter` is an inner-class `FragmentPagerAdapter` that returns some fragments, nothing interesting

The `activity_main`, again pretty standard:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<!--
This title strip will display the currently visible page title, as well as the page
titles for adjacent pages.
-->

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#555555"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: The thing you're seing above the picture is the default dialog titlebar. You can remove it by calling 
  getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); in your dialogFragments onCreateView, before you inflate your view

Comment: Woah. that was easy :D, thanks. that's one thing taken care of at least :) . Care to add what you think is the best method to do this? is this a good way, with the dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a dialogFragment does in my opinion seem like a good way to go, and it is certainly one of the easiest.

Additionally you could make your dialogFragment fullscreen, if that is appropriate, like this:
Create a custom Dialog style in values/styles.xml

```
<!-- DIALOG STYLE -->
<style name="Your.Dialog" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog" >
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
</style>
```

and then set the style where you call the fragment, like this:

```
    myDialogFragment dialog = new myDialogFragment ();
    dialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.Your_Dialog );
    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "fragment_tag");
```

Comment: Can I do a setStyle? Your comment did work, but I can't seem to call setStyle on the dialog though

Comment: Whoops, my mistake. Updated the answer.